# EGL_emulation(1005): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented with MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, android-emulator

Sorry for duplicate question. I don't find best solution. I want to load mysql data to a spinner in my android applicaton but my spinner is empty. Anybody know what causes this error ?? if the cause is about my code i will give my codes. I think this is not caused by my code. I need some help.

```
01-20 03:10:09.270: W/EGL_emulation(1005): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 03:10:10.490: W/InputEventReceiver(1005): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Comment: Have you registered a broadcast receiver or something?